# Notification emails not sent to admin or customer if customer not logged in

Tags: cartthrob

Thi seems really odd, as all other notifications are sent successfully, but no emails are sent when a guest makes a purchase (via SagePay), and from my testing it seems the basket is not cleared. I turned on email logging to verify this.

Is it a CT bug or is it just me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one wasn't a CartThrob bug - there was a problem with a third-party payment module which was breaking guest checkout.